# Android: Finishing an activity with animation effect

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have two activities Main and Temp.
I am calling `Activity Temp` and applying the following animation `getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);`

to get that Temp activity from right to left.
Now i want to finish that `Activity Temp` with reverse animation..
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes its possible by giving

```
overridePendingTransition(enterAnim, exitAnim);
```

When you start the temp activity call this meathod giving enter and exit animation for that particular activity. Then that activity will only finish with an animation. If thats not working you can also call the `overridePendingTransition` in the `onFinish();` of temp activity. So that while finishing it will end up with the animation you give.

Comment: Thank you.I have completed this.

Comment: If my answer helped you promote me upvoting.. good to help you..Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

slide_in_left and slide_out_right exist in your default anim resources.

In your Main Activity, to open Temp (in your onClick):

```
finish();
Intent i2 = new Intent(Main.this, Temp.class);
startActivity(i2);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

In your Temp activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    Intent i2 = new Intent(Temp.this, Main.class);
    startActivity(i2);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                    android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```